# Индексация списка списков

Tags: python, список, индексация

```
L = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]], 
    [[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]], 
    [[41, 42, 43, 44, 45], [46, [47, 48], 49, 50], [51, 52, 53, 54, 55], [56, 57, 58, 59, 60]], 
    [61, 62, 63, [64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71], 72, 73, 74, [75, [76, 77, 78], 79], 80], 
    [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]
```

Из приведенного выше списка списков выведите с помощью индексов число '7'.

Не понимаю, то ли во входных данных ошибка, то ли что-то не усвоил.
Пробовал и 6 и 7 индекс подавать и срез, выводит все, что угодно, но не 7

```
L['7']
L[0:1]
(L.index(6))
print(L.index('7'))
L[0:6]
```

Comment: что-то я не вижу там числа `7` в массиве, например `21` можно было бы вывести как `[0][0]`, а число `48` как `[3][2][1]`... в - вот когда поменяли код теперь вижу :)

Comment: У вас список в списке в списке, соответственно, надо несколько раз срез применить, вернее индексацию: `L[0][0][6]`

Comment: Причём, в `L[0:1]` ведь есть нужный результат внутри, нужно было просто пойти дальше, и от этого среза брать срез и дошли бы сами до нужного результата.

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, с горем пополам въехал, тройное вложение не встречал ранее.

Answer (score 1):

можно сделать так:

```
L = [[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]],
    [[21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30], [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40]],
    [[41, 42, 43, 44, 45], [46, [47, 48], 49, 50], [51, 52, 53, 54, 55], [56, 57, 58, 59, 60]],
    [61, 62, 63, [64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71], 72, 73, 74, [75, [76, 77, 78], 79], 80],
    [81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100]]


def found_in_list(arr, value, index = []):
    for obj in enumerate(arr):
        index_new = index + [obj[0]]
        if type(obj[1]) == list:
            found_in_list(obj[1], value, index_new)
        else:
            if obj[1] == value:
                print(index_new)


found_in_list(L, 48)
```

Comment: Default argument value is mutable ;)

Comment: @Jack_oS, а у меня в pycharm все ок, ну можно если приперло делать без значения по умолчанию :) а уже в первую функцию в явном виде передавать `[]`

Comment: Можно :D Но нужно чуть ли не в одну строку сделать, зачем столько кода лишнего?)

Comment: @Zhihar проверил: мой pycharm подсвечивает...  а вообще зачем там index = [] в аргументах? чтоб можно было передать found_in_list(L, 7, [1, 2, 3]) и получить на выход [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 6]?.. просто инициализировать в нечале ф-ции index = [] - не правильнее разве?

Comment: @mususu как в одну строку сделать, не поделитесь?

Comment: @Jack_oS L[0][0][6] ??

Comment: @Jack_oS я понял, вы пошли от обратного :D можно руками найти индекс, а можно как вы, поиск индекса в зависимости от конкретного числа.

Comment: @Zhihar прикольно конечно, только это уже уровень выше.

Comment: @mususu т.е. когда искомое поменяется с 7 на 77, например, снова брать карандаш и вычислять его индекс? а если L не на 100, а на 10**6 элементов и с уровнями вложения еще глубже (по 20-30 вглубь) - тратим на это пару-тройку дней?.. Zhihar дал вам универсальный алгоритм поиска индекса, какой бы ни был список

Comment: @Zhihar В питоне просто default аргументы инициализируются один раз, при повторном вызове функции сюрприз может быть - список будет уже не пустой, если он поменяется в функции. В вашем случае это не важно - вы не меняете список в функции. Но лучше так не делать, чтобы не привыкать. Для mutable аргументов использовать только `= None`.